# Bug with appcompat using CAB, only in S4

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat, contextual-action-bar

This only happens in the Samsung S4. I try it in samsung s2, nexus 4, htc one, and it works fine. I generate my actionbar using this:
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/
Here is a screenshot in samsung s2 and s4: [image]:

[image]

Comment: I found the answer. The page http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ doesn't generate the resources for xxhdpi and I don't know why, but if we don't have the xxhdpi resources, the appcompat-actionbar use the resources from mdpi